# How can I randomly select values from a very large number of permutations without causing memory issues?

Tags: python, random, permutation, python-itertools, large-data

I am solving one machine scheduling problem and the data set is very large. I need to obtain a subset of permutations (with a pre-defined selected_number: How many numbers I want to get from the permutations) from the permutation results, and the selected permutations need to be randomized.

for example, if my machine 1 has 15 jobs, then all possible permutations would be 15! It is impossible to append all the sequences in the list for the large number of permutations, it may cause a lack of memory.

```
perms = list(permutations(self.machines[m]))
selected_perms = random.sample(perms, num_selected)
```

So I try in two ways:
(1)Randomly select permutations and add to a list (select all machines), ensuring randomness: But the first way is pretty slow, I have no idea why does it happened.

```
selected_perms = []
                    
while selected_perms.__len__() < num_selected:
  job_perms =  random.sample((list(self.machines[m])), 15)
  if job_perms not in selected_perms:
    selected_perms.append(job_perms)
```

(2) Shuffle the machine sequence first, and then select a subset of the permutations. However, this way does not perform well because the randomness is poor.

```
perms =  random.sample((list(self.machines[m])), job_count)
selected_perms = list(islice(permutations(perms), num_selected))
```

(3)I have an idea to improve method 2. First, Shuffle the machine sequence first and select smaller selection permutations. Then, repeat this process multiple times to reach the total selection number. However, I believe that this approach may only yield slightly better results than method 2.

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Answer (score 1):

There is a recipe for this in [docs for the random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#recipes):

```
def random_permutation(iterable, r=None):
    "Random selection from itertools.permutations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    r = len(pool) if r is None else r
    return tuple(random.sample(pool, r))
```

To make *k* random selections without a replacement, just use a loop with a rejection step for a rare duplicate:

```
k = 15
seen = set()
for i in range(k):
    selection = random_permutation(pool, r)
    while selection in seen:
        selection = random_permutation(pool, r)
    seen.add(selection)
    print(selection)
```

Comment: Loop and reject dupes is their (1) way already. Might be good to point out why yours is better.

Comment: That's... not really a reason. They said theirs *"is pretty slow, I have no idea why does it happened"*. What I meant is that yours keeps track of the seen selections with a **set** instead of a **list**. Clearly they don't understand that their list usage is slow, so I find it worth pointing that out.

Comment: @KellyBundy Please stop the sniping. You do it to many people on many answers and have been doing so for a long time.  If you have something productive to add, like an answer of your own, please make an actual contribution.  Otherwise, you serve only to increase negativity and to drive respondents away from StackOverflow.  The continued hostily is abusive.

Comment: I really don't see how ***suggesting improvements*** isn't productive / a contribution and is negative or even hostile/abusive. But ok, I'll try to remember that you're one of the few who dislike it...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than producing all permutations, you could use a Numpy generator which minimises memory usage:

```
import numpy as np

size = 15
chosen = 8
number = 7

rng = np.random.default_rng()
for _ in range(number):
    print(rng.choice(size, chosen, replace = False))
```

which produces output like:

```
[ 8  5  3  1 10  7 14 11]
[ 2  1 11  9  4 14 13  7]
[10  4  7  5  1  3  8 14]
[ 4 10 14 13  6 12  1  5]
[13  3  2 12  0  6  4  1]
[ 3 12  4 13  5  6  7  2]
[ 2 10 13  7  0  8 12  3]
```